# Jenkins Java Option

Tags: java, jenkins

I am unable to find the JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS. There is no jenkins.xml file under C:\Users\my_user_account \ .jenkins. I am using windows 8 and i running tomcat server. I am trying to set "-Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable" as true. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: How do you run Jenkins in Windows? Script/service?

Comment: I start tom cat server. Jenkins war file is in the webapps. I just go the URL locahost:8080\Jenkins. It is not as a windows service @Salem

Comment: Try to add `set "JENKINS_JAVA_OPTS=-Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable"` to `catalina.bat` or `startup.bat` (both in tomcat dir/bin).

Comment: @Salem How to add ? I am sorry , i am new to scripting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file named `setenv.bat` in `your_tomcat_directory/bin` with the following content:

```
set JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable
```

If you use notepad check that it is not saved as `setenv.bat.txt`

Comment: the just start the tom cat server as usual? @Salem

Comment: yes. If you run it with the batch script (not the one you just created) or a desktop shortcut to it, it should load those env vars.

Comment: I normally clicks startup.bat to run the tomcat server. Hope that what u mean. @Salem